# Show that $W_1 \subset W_2$ if and only if $W_2^0\subset W_1^0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional subspace over $F$. $W_1, W_2$ are subspaces of $V$. Show that $W_1 \subset W_2$ if and only if $W_2^0 \subset W_1^0$.

I have proved one direction but I am stuck proving the reverse direction. That is, how do I show that if the annihilator of $W_2$ is contained in the annihilator of $W_2$ then $W_2$ contains $W_1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to prove that $W_1 \not \subset W_2 \implies W_2^0 \not \subset W_1^0$.

In particular, let $x$ be an element of $W_1$ that is not in $W_2$ (note that $x \neq 0$). In short: take $f$ to be the dual map to $x$. Then $f$ annihilates $W_2$, but not $W_1$.

In long: let $x_1 = x$.  Let $x_2,\dots,x_k$ be a basis for $W_2$.  Extend $\{x_1,\dots,x_k\}$ to a basis $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ over $V$.  Define $f$ over this basis by
$$
f(x_i) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & i=1\\
0 & i \neq 1
\end{cases}
$$
we have now defined a unique linear functional $f$.  This $f$ annihilates $W_2$, but not $W_1$.